# A model which belongs to more than one other model simultaneously

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations

With the following associations:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
  has_many :comments
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :post
end
```

I can do something like this in the controller:

```
@comment = current_user.comments.new(comment_params)
@comment.user
```

But to access the associated `Post` I need to manually set it's parent:

```
@comment.post = Post.find params[:post_id]
```

Is there a better way for doing this, when a new `Comment` is created?

Comment: Are your resources nested? It looks like they are.

Comment: No they are not yet.

Comment: can you provide your schema for user post and comment?

Comment: `belongs_to` method should only be used if this class contains the foreign key. So do you have `user_id` and `post_id` in your `Comment` model?

Comment: @AzatGataoulline Yes, I have.

Comment: @ABrowne Because `Comment` doesn't have a post instance method.

Comment: @comment.post.user would return the user of the post rather than the comment which is not what you are looking for. Therefore to acheive what you wish to do, when the comment is created you can just set the post_id within you comment_params and ensure that you have set that field as write accessible within comment.

Comment: what does `comment_params` contain? and what is the URL that this request is posted to, is it something like `/post/:id/comments` ?

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady `comment_params` contains `:body` and `:comment_id` and the url is `/comments`

Comment: @Sajjad try to add the `:post_id` to the `comment_params`

Comment: @Sajjad wait, is this an update ? why would it contain `:comment_id` ?

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady Sorry, I made a mistake. I mean `:post_id` not `:comment_id`

Comment: well it should work fine, when you call `@comment.post` you get nil ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105017/discussion-between-mohammad-abushady-and-sajjad).

Answer (score 1):

I would use nested resources

```
resources :posts do
  resources :comments
end
```

Then I would build the comment through the post and merge in the current user's id so that you don't need hidden fields which can then obviously be manipulated.

```
class CommentsController
  def new
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.new
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.new(comment_params)
  end

  private

  def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:content).merge({ user_id: current_user.id })
  end

end
```

You'd only really need to merge the current user on creating the comment so you could have a private comment_creation_params method that gets called on create

```
def comment_params
  params.require(:comment).permit(:content)
end

def comment_creation_params
  comment_params.merge({ user_id: current_user.id })
end
```

Comment: I think it's more to display the comments on the post's show page, and who posted them.  What create callback?  Do you mean the create action?  The is what I say at the bottom.  In the create action you would then use `@comment = @post.comments.new(comment_creation_params)`

Comment: This only solves this special case but adds another problem: I can't do `@comment.user` to access the user and generally I can't benefit from the features added by `belongs_to :user`

Comment: @Sajjad why not, just add in `belongs_to :user`, then you can do `@comment.user`

Comment: Sorry about the confusion, In rails console when I try `@comment.post` I get the associated post. But in controller I get nil. also comment_params contains `:body` and `:comment_id` but I still get nil either before or after `@comment.save`

Comment: @Sajjad, this seems like a seperate issue to me.  Can you post a seperate question with your controller code in it.

Answer (score 0):

So, the main idea just to get rid of `Post.find(params[:post_id])`.

If I were you I would insert `post_id` in `comment_params` explicitly:

```
def comment_params
  params.require(:comment).permit(:text).merge(post_id: params[:post_id])
end
```

Just to ensure that post exists I would add validation to comment:

```
class Comment
  validates :post, presence: true
  #...
end
```

If you don't want to associate a comment with a post you may just skip this validation or write a custom one

```
validate do
  errors.add(:post_id, 'There is no post') unless Post.find(post_id).present?
end
```

One of the answers suggests solution with nested resources, which is another workaround.

Comment: The issue with my code is that, I can't use @comment.post to access the assoicated post, not associating a `Comment` with a `Post`

Comment: @Sajjad, why don't you want a Comment to be associated with Post when a comment belongs to post as a matter of fact?

Comment: @Sajjad, i've edited my answer. There no need to add validation at all, `comment_params` does the trick.

Comment: Sorry if I expressed what I mean so badly. I meant I don't have any problem with associating an instance of `Comment` with an instance of `Post`

Answer (score -2):

If you wanted the comments object to be assoicated to either or, then a polymorphic association would work.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable
end

class Posts < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable
end
```

You'll not be able to use @comment.post, but you will be able to do @comment.commentable which will either be your Post or User object depending on which one is associated to that instance.

Comment: In my code both `Post` and `User` are associated to `Comment`.

Comment: He wants it to belong to both, with multiple `belongs_to` as I understand it, not one or the other.

Comment: @ABrowne, this is not a comment about a user. This is a comment about post made by user. Both fields are required

Comment: I made an incorrect assumption when I first read the post. I assumed its a comment that would left against a user or a post, rather than what the OP meant, which as you state looks like a comment on a post made by a user.